# Using an if/else statement within a query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query where I'd like to convert `o.interval` from seconds to days but only if the `o.interval_type` for that row is set to "interval". If it's set to "day" then I'd just like to output the `o.interval` instead.

```
SELECT o.id as "Sub ID" ,
o.customer_id as "Customer ID",
o.status as "Status",
FROM_UNIXTIME(o.start_date) as "Start Date",
FROM_UNIXTIME(o.last_processed) as "Last Processed",
o.interval_type as "Interval Type",
CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(o.interval)) / 24)) as "Interval"
FROM subscriptions as o
```

How can I encorporate an if/else statement?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if `IF(o.interval_type = 'day', o.interval, CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(o.interval)) / 24)) as "Interval"`

Comment: I'd recommend CASE, not IF...

Comment: @Akina can you expand on why you would recommend that?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones CASE statement is described in standard whereas IF() function is not (moreover, IF is not reserved word in, for example, SQL-92).

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(
  o.interval_type = 'interval',
  CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(o.interval)) / 24)),
  o.interval
) AS "Interval"
```

If the condition (`o.interval_type = 'interval'`) is true then the expression evaluates to `CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(o.interval)) / 24))`, otherwise it evaluates to `o.interval`.